# Is it possible to query the CKAN datastore with comparisons other than exact matching?

Tags: postgresql, datastore, ckan

Is it possible to pass any of the comparison operators listed here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparison.html to the datastore_search api?

I'm aware of the datastore_search_sql function, but it seems like pretty bad practice to be passing sql queries directly from the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid `datastore_search` only does `=`. See https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckanext/datastore/backend/postgres.py#L341 This API call is designed for simple filtering and sorting - mirroring the controls in the resource preview widget.

I'm not clear about your situation - frontend sending SQL queries. But I don't see much different between using `datastore_search_sql` and `datastore_search`. They are both relatively simple wrappers around Postgres SQL.

Comment: In this case, I'm working on a way visually filter rows using comparison operators. As in this issue: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/4406 the plugin that they've made public appears to use azure object storage. Might be missing something obvious here.